# MultipartEntity отправка текста через StringBody: русские буквы отправляются знаком "?"

Tags: java, android

Отправляю текст и файл. Такая беда,что сервер получает[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

знак ? вместо русских слов.
Беру текст из edittext:

```
 name = nameFF.getText().toString().trim();
        naselpunkt = naspunkt.getText().toString().trim();

        street = ulica.getText().toString().trim();

        house = dom.getText().toString().trim();

        e_mail = email.getText().toString().trim();

        message = mesages.getText().toString().trim();
```

Нашел в сети такой способ:
Было так и отправлялись знаки вопроса:

```
 MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
```

Изменил на этот вариант но ничего не изменилось.

```
 MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE,null, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Вот так добавляю:

```
entity.addPart(KEY_NAME, new StringBody(name));
            entity.addPart(KEY_NASELPUNKT, new StringBody(naselpunkt));
            entity.addPart(KEY_STREET, new StringBody(street));
            entity.addPart(KEY_DOM, new StringBody(house));
            entity.addPart(KEY_EMAIL, new StringBody(e_mail));
            entity.addPart(KEY_MESAGES, new StringBody(message));
```

Answer (score 2):

Решил проблему банальным путем:

```
  Charset chars = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

            entity.addPart(KEY_NAME, new StringBody(name , chars));
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так нужно отправлять, чтобы не было знаков вопроса

```
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.addBinaryBody("company", yourKirillicString.getBytes())
builder.build();
```

Comment: эм . что-то не то

Comment: @upward `MultipartEntity` deprecated, вместо этого нужно использовать `MultipartEntityBuilder`